# How to Convert to DateTime

Tags: python, regex, datetime, csv

I have CSV files that has among other things, dates in them, that looks like:

```
2014-01-25 00:14:08.000
```

Now I parse the CSV file and get the dates. Then I run a regex to check if the date is valid(matches the format as above) then I convert the date from the CSV file to  DateTime.

This how ever gives me a `ValueError:` that states: `need more than 3 values to unpack`.
The CSV file can contain Thousands of records with dates like the above mentioned.

My regex:

```
date_re_time_norm = re.compile("""^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[ ](\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d)$""", re.I)
```

My convert method:

```
def convert_date(self, dstring):
    if self.date_re_time_norm.match(dstring):
        year, month, day, hour, minute, second = str(dstring).split('-')
    return datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day), int(hour), int(minute), int(second), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Method is shortened for readability.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be much better to use [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime("2014-01-25 00:14:08.000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

This can replace both of your regular expressions, as it will parse the date if in an appropriate format or raise an error if not:

```
def convert_date(self, dstring, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(dstring, format)
    except ValueError:
        # wrong format
```

(you could make the format string a class or instance attribute as necessary).

---

**Edit:** If you are determined to stick with the regexs, you will need to do more splitting:

```
date, time = dstring.split(" ")
year, month, day = date.split("-")
hour, minute, second = time.split(":")
second = second.split(".")[0]
return datetime(*map(int, (year, month, day, hour, minute, second)))
```

In Python, however, ["There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and that way is `strptime`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am looking for something similar to what I have...

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly, but I think you are needlessly reinventing the metaphorical wheel.

Answer (score 3):

You are splitting on hyphens, and there are only two of those, so you only get three elements in the list:

```
['2014', '01', '25 00:14:08.000']
```

See @jonrsharpe's answer for a better way.